# Add Resources to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

I'm trying to change icon to custom one, in WIN32 C++, but I can't find where to add my own resources?

Websites tell me to look at my project's properties and there should be a 'resource' tab but there isn't. It just has general properties (such as unicode/multibyte or debugging settings)

Most of the tutorials/faqs I've seen are for VS 2008 but I'm stuck with VS 2010, did it change or something?

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition

Comment: What you've seen so far are instructions for managed projects.  MSVC++ uses a different resource mechanism.  Project + Add New Item, Resources, Resource File.

Comment: @HansPassant, if I go to Add New Item; there is no Resource option, only .cpp, .h, Windows Form, Property Sheet and Component Class.

Comment: Be sure to mention that you are using the Express edition in your questions.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that would make a difference, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express Edition does not include a resource editor. Instead you can use [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) for creating the resource script and the header file.

After that you can add these files to your project by using the [Solution explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26k97dbc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Right-Click on resource files and choose Add/Existing Item and select the resource script you have created. Do the same with your header file.

Answer (score 1):

Project -> "Project Name" Properties -> Application -> Resources group box -> Icon and manifest.

Does that work?

Comment: It doesn't, he's using C++, not C#.

Comment: I don't see any Application tab or menu

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to open project properties, not solution properties. Inside -> Configuration properties -> Resources -> General -> Resource File Name. It seems that you can specify only one .res file though.

However if you create a new WinAPI C++ project from scratch, it will automatically create a folder Resource Files in the project, containing the current icon. You can then use the boilerplate code to set your own in the same fashion.

Comment: I only see General/Debugging/VC++/Directories/CC++/Linker/Manifest/XML/Browse/Build/Custom Build

Comment: Have you ported the project from another VS version? How about trying to create a new project from the templates? Do you still see only the Custom Build settings?

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread because I was looking for how to reopen the Resource View tab to edit the application version number.  I couldn't find any direct menu control to get it.

The solution for me was to find the existing resource file (*.rc) in the Solution Explorer, and either double-click it, or right-click -> Open.